# Eclim - What to set org.eclim.java.run.mainclass to?

Tags: java, vim, eclim

I'm having trouble getting the :Java command to work in eclim.  When I run it I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Required setting 'org.eclim.java.run.mainclass' has not been set.
    at org.eclim.plugin.jdt.command.src.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:107)
    at org.eclim.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:334)
```

There seems to be a lot of explainations as how to fix this, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945886/how-to-run-a-java-program-using-eclim) post on SO or [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1361537), but they all say to "setting the org.eclim.java.run.mainclass property of your project" through :ProjectSettings.  My question is what do I set it to? No matter what I put when I try to write the changes vim says "Operation contained errors.  See location list for details."

Answer (score 9):

As I landed here from Google, I will post an answer:

You need to set the name of the class with `main` method. So for example, if you have just one class:

```
class HelloKittieTest {
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Hello Kittie");
  }
}
```

Save the file, run `:ProjectSettings` command which will open the mentioned file and set:

```
org.eclim.java.run.mainclass=HelloKittieTest
```

Don't forget to save that one too. Now you should normally run `:Java`

Answer (score 5):

@Ernest's answer is correct to run the main class for a project. However, if you want to run the main  method for an arbitrary class you only need to pass the current file token `%` as an argument to the `:Java` command...

```
public class Foo{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("I came from Foo");
    }
}
```

In command mode pass the current file token (%).

```
:Java %
```

Answer (score 0):

though I have an entry "<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>" in .classpath, but it seems that you also need to run :NewSrcEntry src again to trigger eclim to refresh relative configuration.